# Swap 2D array's rows and columns

Tags: arrays, csv, autoit, transpose

I need to get columns from a CSV file into an array (multidimensional array or array of arrays). I used [CSV.au3](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/114406-csv-file-to-multidimensional-array/#comment-799820) which loads the *rows* just fine, but I need the *columns* in that place. My CSV file looks like:

```
Item 1, Item 2, Another Item
Item 3, Item 4
```

It creates a multidimensional array that looks like:

```
$aResult[0] = [0] => 'Item 1', [1] => 'Item 2', [2] => 'Another Item'
$aResult[1] = [0] => 'Item 3', [1] => 'Item 4'
```

Where I would like it to look like:

```
$aResult[0] = [0] => 'Item 1', [1] => 'Item 3'
$aResult[1] = [0] => 'Item 2', [1] => 'Item 4'
$aResult[2] = [0] => 'Another Item'
```

For each row it should contain the column not the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a break from this project for a while, and ended up figuring it out myself:

```
;Load the first line into an array (for our Count Later)
$columnsCounter = StringSplit($content[1], ",")
;Here we use the row count (from $content) and column count (from $columnsCounter)
;We define an array that is the perfect size for our Menu Items
Dim $MenuItems[$content[0] + 1][$columnsCounter[0] + 1]

; Now we loop through each row and column
For $x = 1 To ($content[0]) - 1
    ;Create an array with the row we are looking at
    $oneRow = StringSplit($content[$x], ",")
    ;now loop through each column
    For $y = 1 To ($columnsCounter[0])
        ;Grab the item we want and add it to our menu items array
        $MenuItems[$x][$y] = $oneRow[$y]
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is CSV to 2D Array example. [Credits to Malkey](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/96357-csv-to-2d-array-with-regexp/?tab=comments#comment-692864).

```
#include <array.au3>

Opt("MustDeclareVars", 1)

Dim $sCSV = '"010","2","03"' & @CRLF & _
        '"24","30","20"' & @CRLF & _
        '"txt","bla","toto"'

Local $arr = _CsvToArray2D($sCSV)
_ArrayDisplay($arr)

; Converts CSV format to a 2D array.
Func _CsvToArray2D($sCSV)
    Local $aTmp = StringRegExp($sCSV & @CR, '(\V*)\v{1,2}', 3)
    Local $NumCols[UBound($aTmp)]
    For $x = 0 To UBound($aTmp) - 1
        StringReplace($aTmp[$x], ",", ",")
        $NumCols[$x] = @extended + 1
    Next
    Local $Max = _ArrayMax($NumCols, 1)

    Dim $aArr[UBound($aTmp)][$Max]

    For $i = 0 To UBound($aArr, 1) - 1
        Local $aTemp = StringSplit($aTmp[$i], ",")
        For $j = 0 To $aTemp[0] - 1
            $aArr[$i][$j] = $aTemp[$j + 1]
        Next
    Next
    Return $aArr
EndFunc  ;==>_CsvToArray2D
;========> End of _CsvToArray2D ======================
```

Answer (score 0):

### Transpose array

> … it should contain the column not the row.

As per [Documentation - Function Reference - `_ArrayTranspose()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_ArrayTranspose.htm) :

> Transposes a 1D or 2D array (swaps rows and columns)

### CSV file to array

> … get the Columns in CSV file and load them into an array …

CSV file to 2-dimensional array, as per [Documentation - Function Reference - `_FileReadToArray()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_FileReadToArray.htm) :

> Reads the specified file into a 1D or 2D array

Example:

```
#include <File.au3> ; _FileReadToArray() and $FRTA_NOCOUNT
#include <Array.au3>; _ArrayDisplay()

Global Const $g_sFileCSV         = 'C:\file.csv'
Global Const $g_sDelimiterColumn = ','

Global       $g_aCSV

_FileReadToArray($g_sFileCSV, $g_aCSV, $FRTA_NOCOUNT, $g_sDelimiterColumn)

If @error Then    
    ConsoleWrite('_FileReadToArray() error: ' & @error & @LF)    
Else    
    _ArrayDisplay($g_aCSV)    
EndIf
```

### Array to CSV file

[`_FileWriteFromArray()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_FileWriteFromArray.htm) saves array as text file.